# How to use Freezed package with Bloc in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, freezed

I want to create a simple bloc with freezed package. This is my bloc:

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:presentation/presentation_index.dart';

part 'auth_bloc_event.dart';
part 'auth_bloc_state.dart';

class AuthBlocBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  final SignUpBuyerUseCase signUpBuyerUseCase;

  AuthBlocBloc(this.signUpBuyerUseCase) : super(AuthState.initial());

  @override
  Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(
    AuthEvent event,
  ) async* {
    yield* event.map();
    
  }
}
```

and my event class :

```
part of 'auth_bloc.dart';

@freezed
abstract class AuthEvent with _$AuthEvent {
  const factory AuthEvent.login(String username, String password) = Login;
  const factory AuthEvent.signUpBuyer(BuyerEntity entity) = SignUpBuyer;
}
```

and state class :

```
part of 'auth_bloc.dart';

@freezed
abstract class AuthState with _$AuthState {
  const factory AuthState.initial() = InitialAuthState;
  const factory AuthState.signUpBuyerFail(String error) = SignUpBuyerFail;
  const factory AuthState.signUpBuyerSuccess() = SignUpBuyerSuccess;
  const factory AuthState.signUpBuyerLoading() = SignUpBuyerLoading;
}
```

The problem is that when i try to run

> flutter pub run build_runner watch --deleteonflicting-outputs

Nothing happens and no classes are generated

Answer (score 2):

In the bloc, you should try to include the freezed file.

```
part 'auth_bloc_event.dart';
part 'auth_bloc_state.dart';
part 'auth_bloc.freezed.dart';
```